# Can I compile legacy MFC applications with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I maintain several old MFC applications using Visual Studio 7 and I was considering upgrading to Visual Studio 2008. After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions#86614), I realise that the Express edition will not be able to do this.

Does anyone know if I will be able to compile old MFC apps with VS2008 Standard edition or will I need to get the more expensive Professional edition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have everything you need to build an MFC application with Standard edition.  Be warned, though, if it is an application of any size or complexity it will not simply be a matter of upgrading the project/solution files and hitting F5.  There are plenty of breaking changes between VS7 and 2008, most introduced in the V8 compiler. Roll up your sleeves.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Standard edition includes support for MFC/ATL.

FYI you can [compare the features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2008/products/cc149003.aspx)