# "Multi-threaded Debugging" feature missing in VC++ 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've seen [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions) that there are some missing features in the VC++ 2008 Express debugger, particularly related to multi-threaded debugging. I've tried debugging a multi-threaded program in Visual C++ 2008 Express and it seemed to work fine. What is really missing?

Looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx) (as mentioned in one answer), I found:

"Multithreaded/Multiprocess Debugging is easier with an improved Threads window and other user interface improvements to make multithreaded debugging easier"

But it is still not clear what is really missing...

Answer (score 1):

Visual C++ 2008 Express **lacks** the following features:

- Dumps enable you to save program information for debugging at a later time
- Attach to Remote Process enables you to attach the debugger to processes on remote computers that have been set up for remote debugging

Also, Visual C++ 2008 Express does not include OpenMP support, 64-bit compilers, or a resource editor.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc149003.aspx

These resources might also be of interest:

[Visual Studio Express FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/)

[Visual Studio 2008 Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express)