# Visual Studio 2005 Express Edition license

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

I am going to develop one application using Visual C# 2005 Express Edition specially in c#.
Actually this a commercial application for One of my client. Is it legal to sale this application for me and also for my client. What are limitations of this edition for commercial purpose...please help.Thanx in advance

Comment: Why don't you get the 2008 editions? They're more up to date (obviously) and are under the same non-restrictive licence - see link at http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/ (offline install down the bottom).

Comment: This question is a subset of the one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions

Answer (score 1):

Please see the FAQ:

[Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/)

> there are no licensing restrictions
>   for applications built using Visual
>   Studio Express Editions.

Answer (score 0):

In this spirit - you can use the VS 2008 Express edition as well... Newer, Better, and Also Free...