# Software Licensing

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, licensing

Is it ok to develop a Payroll System for a small company using Visual Studio 2005 Express and MS SQL Sever 2005 Express Edition?

Comment: Yes. The Express editions are fully functional apart from the ability to host plugins. There are no restrictions on what you can develop.

Comment: See - [SQL server Express licensing]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320954/sql-server-2008-express-edition-licensing) and [Visual Studio Express licensing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635500/visual-studio-2005-express-edition-license)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is.

The express editions *can* be used for commercial purposes.

See the [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/support-faq.aspx):

> - Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?
>
> Yes, there are no licensing restrictions for applications built using Visual Studio Express Editions.

Comment: For development sure... but can they actually RUN the system in Production off the Express edition?

Comment: @Fosco - What do you mean? A compiled application does not need an express edition to run. And if it did, it is free to download ;)

Comment: He specified SQL Server Express, so this is about more than just writing the GUI.  But it appears it can be used commercially, so I am surprised.

Comment: @Fosco - You mean the limitations of SQL Server Express?

Comment: @Fosco - MS recommend using it for some application. And some enterprising souls have use multiple instances on VMs as load balanced SQL Servers :)