# Trouble with visual studio file extensions (.vdproj)

Tags: visual-studio, vdproj

I'm trying to open an open source project and I'm getting an error when trying to open a certain component of the project. I'm using Visual Studio C# 2008 Express Edition and I'm opening a .sln file. That part of the file opens fine, but when I enter the IDE I'm greeted immediately with the error:

> ...DinamapSetup.vdproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.vdproj) is not supported by this version of the application.

I've been searching around to what I might need to open this file, but I haven't figured it out. I've discovered it is a "Setup and Deployment Project" file, but I can't seem to get any information about what is keeping this from opening.

Is this not file extension not supported in the express edition? Am I using the wrong version of visual studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Express Editions don't support setup projects:

- [What is "missing" in the Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions)

Answer (score 0):

Want to add this, because I spent way too long trying to figure it out:
But the "shell" versions don't allow you to open these types of projects either. (I didn't realize VS Shell was installed on my work computer.)