# how do I open a solution that has a vdproj in it in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vdproj

I think the correct answer is "just open it" but I can't because of this error message:

[image: error when opening]

I'm using VS 2010 `10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel`. Is there something I have to install to get it to open solutions that use `vdproj` files?

(changing over to a Wix file is not an option)

Comment: You're not using [VS express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670312/trouble-with-visual-studio-file-extensions-vdproj) are you?

Comment: No. I found the SO post related to that before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was to re-install Visual Studio 2010. Lame, but it worked. I looked for a config utility for the VS2010 install (the usual Repair, Remove, Configure dialog) but couldn't find it.