# Going from Visual Studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2010 Express Editions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I use C# and asp.net in visual studio 2008 standard.  I just found out that there is no Visual studio 2010 standard.

I can't really afford Visual studio 2010 Pro.

So what am I going to lose when (if) I start using 
C# 2010 express
web dev 2010 express

Comment: Right, there is no VS2010.  Only a beta.  The Ultimate edition is a free download.  Pricing for the RTM hasn't been set yet afaik, how do you know you can't afford it?

Comment: @nobugz: Visual Studio 2010 will be more than a hundred bucks (or close below it) for sure...and there are people who can't afford that.

Comment: I know I can't afford it because I saw a preview of their prices.  Standard was around 200 dollars and pro was 800+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions), it has a complete list.

Answer (score 3):

Prices were leaked here: [Microsoft names Visual Studio 2010 dates](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/10/19/visual_studio_2010_second_beta_packaging/). There is no Standard edition, Visual Studio 2010 Professional will be priced at $799, ooouuuuch!!!

Comment: There is an upgrade version of Visual Studio 2010 Professional (p/n C5E-00539) for users of VS 2005/2008 Standard. Costs about $260 at various online retailers. It seems to be a limited time promotion.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the express editions of VS 2010 and here's what I've found to be missing compared to VS 2008 Pro:

- No support for plugins at all (e.g. no Resharper or what not)
- No windows Service template (this is really odd as this exists in VS 2008 C# express edition, so it must've been removed from 2008 express to 2010 express)

And that's pretty much it, there are probably other things missing too, however I haven't come across anything else.

I've used VS 2008 express editions at home for a long time (and now 2010 express), but run VS 2008 Pro at work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'this exists in VS 2008 C# express edition'?  When you say VS 2008 which edition are you referring to?

Comment: That could be clearer yes - what I mean is the Windows service template is missing in VS 2010 C# express, whilst it exists in VS 2008 C# express.
They apparently removed it from 2008 to 2010 Express edition.