# Visual Studio Express - console window as a tab

Tags: visual-c++, configuration, visual-studio-2010, console, window

I wonder, if there is a way to make VS C++ Express console window appear as tab, like 'Output' or 'Code Definition Window', rather than new window (the same way like Eclipse does). Any IDE settings or plugin?

Thanks in advance,

Regards, Pawel (PL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to create a visual studio plugin to do this, and from the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions) you can see that the top listed item that's missing is:

> No Add-in/macros

so while you might be able to create one, you won't be able to run it from the Express edition.