# How to write a SourceControl Add-in for VS Express edition

Tags: visual-studio, open-source, visual-studio-express, version-control

As you all know Visual Studio Express edition do not support Source Control Integration and Add in

As it is obvious there is a feature which allows VS tointegrate with any kind of source control. So I'm using VS express for myself (in home, and for my presonal Project and want to use a source control for my projects) So what should I Do

Currently I'm using SVN and by Command Prompt using svn, but I want to create an Add-In for VS Express edition which works with VS Express.

Any help will Appriciate.

---

Update : An example for doing this is to write an application which run beside of VS and by refactoring find the Items and make them capable to work with a sourcecontrol inside of VS express
your solution may be completely different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sam said, you can't write an Add-on.  In my opinion, the best add-in for the full Visual Studio is AnkhSVN and [they have not been able to create one either](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/wiki/Faq#head-5cfda3c01b2ff5bab6b3742c33ced4abe1426eb2).

So I would recommend looking at [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) instead.  It is a complete, mature and Free GUI SVN client, implemented as a Windows Explorer extension.  If you can't integrate into Visual Studio Express, this is the next best thing.

---

Microsoft's Dan Fernandez from the Visual Studio team does discuss on his blog [how TestDriven.NET managed to work around the restrictions in the Express Editions](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielfe/archive/2007/06/01/testdriven-net-and-express-technical-information.aspx).

I recommend against trying this for practical and ethical reasons, but the information is out there, so this answer would not be complete without it.

Comment: @Colin As I told @Sam, I know that there is no support for add-in for VS Express, I'mlooking for a kind of backdoors, tricks, hack or something else which force VS to use it. I also Update my question

Comment: @Nasser Hajloo I have updated my answer.  I don't recommend trying this however.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can as the express editions don't support Add-ins.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions) for some more details

Comment: I know Express don't support Add-in, and it is because I'm looking for a trickor hack to do this, there are always some geek which done this before. I hope I found one here.