# ReSharper 5 installer not recognizing Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2010, resharper

I'm trying to install ReSharper 5. But the installer does not recognize that I've got Visual Studio 2010 Express installed. The installer *does* find my Visual Studio 2008 Team System installation.

I've got a valid ReSharper 5 license.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Express versions of Visual Studio do not support add-ins.

See also [What is “missing” in the Visual Studio Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions)