# Is it possible to write complex web applications (like StackOverflow) in VS Express? What is the first feature you miss in the express edition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express

Many applications (like StackOverflow) has been written by three developers (a small team), would have been possible to do the same job using VS Express Edition?

Which would have been the real differences? Whcih main feature is "enough" to justify the use of VS full edition?

i ask this question not for curiosity but because I want to understand the difference of VS Express vs not Express for a small team. Differences that go beyond the feature matrix.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd reword this to avoid direct reference to Stack Overflow, otherwise it's highly likely to be migrated to http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't refer stackoverflow, it is just to make the sentence clearer. I could have asked "which is the main thing you miss in the VS Express", but StackOVerflow was used as a real world example. Ok, anyway I'll slightly remove the focus on SO.

Comment: I hope as it is now it is ok.

Comment: Other questions that use Stack Overflow as an example have been moved, so my view would be that it's better safe than sorry.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions?

Comment: This is why I didn't want to reword the question. My question was not regarding stack overflow, was regarding "a site like stack overflow", it was quite clear in my opinion. Anyway I don't mind too much, the question is still open, it is not a real duplicate: it speaks of web developement and asks for the main feature missing, not a generic comparison between 2 editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a fully functional web site with the Web Developer Express edition. There are things it doesn't support like plugins (so no resharper), but you can develop Silverlight applications (for example).

So it might have taken a little longer, or certain features might not have been developed straight away, but I would say that you could develop something like Stack Overflow using the Express edition.

There are no restrictions on what you can develop.

[Microsoft site](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/)

Comment: so lack of plugin support is the main feature in this case?

Comment: @user193655 - lack of plugin support is a big issue. I think there are some other restrictions, but I couldn't find the page. However, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions the accepted answer gives a comprehensive list.