# Can Visual Studio 2010 Express connect to Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express, tfs, team-explorer

I know VS 2010 Pro/Premium/Ultimate include TFS connectivity, does VS 2010 Express?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it doesn't.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions) SO question (What is “missing” in the Visual Studio Express Editions?) - one of the bullet points is `no Team Explorer support`, meaning to TFS integration.

On [this](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-gb/products) Microsoft page for VS 2010, you can see the the Pro edition with MSDN essentials subscription has none of the TFS features out of the box, suggesting that this is also the case for the express SKUs.

Comment: The above Microsoft page doesn't say that VS2010 Pro has no TFS features. It is merely stating that MSDN "Essentials" does not come with a TFS license or CAL. VS2010 Pro certainly can connect with TFS!

Comment: @AndrewStephens - I do state that these SKUs do not come with TFS features _out of the box_. That's doesn't mean that they can't connect at all.

Comment: Interestingly, for 2012, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms349441.aspx) says: "As with Visual Studio, you can use Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web to do strong name signing, connect to Team Foundation Server, debug using different web browsers, and manage NuGet packages." BUT presumably you'd still need a TFS CAL?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you can install this http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=329

Though i don't know why you wouldn't be able to install TFS support for free, since microsoft provides a free plugin for Eclipse that you can use.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4240

If you log onto codeplex, it will give you a free key to use this.

Edit: The following link makes it seems like you can use it in VS

https://tfs.discountasp.net/KB/a843/visual-web-developer-20052008-and-visual-studio-2010-express.aspx

> While Visual Web Developer 2005/2008 and Visual Studio 2010 Express will not directly integrate with Team Foundation Server, you can still use the Team Explorer application to connect to your server to check files out for editing.
>
> Assuming that you have already
>   installed Visual Web Developer
>   2005/2008 or Visual Studio 2010
>   Express on your workstation, perform
>   the following step:

```
Download and install Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 - ISO.
```

Comment: Installing Microsoft Visual Studio Team Explorer 2010 will not integrate the Team Explorer in Visual Studio Express. It will open Visual Studio on the side.