# Integrate Visual Basic 2010 Express with Team Foundation Server?

Tags: vb.net, tfs

I've used MS Visual Basic 2010 Express to build a very simple VB.Net Windows app.  I need to check the code into our Team Foundation Server Source Control.  Is there a TFS plug-in for VB Express?  If not, do I need to check the code in manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Visual Studio 2010 Express connect to Team Foundation Server 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907357/can-visual-studio-2010-express-connect-to-team-foundation-server-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it manually as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907357/can-visual-studio-2010-express-connect-to-team-foundation-server-2010) .

Answer (score 1):

Given my experience with TFS I would check the code in manually.  Package it all up nicely and get one changeset for the lot.

Answer (score 1):

TFS isn't supported in any of the express editions of Visual Studio. I'm not sure if TFS is integrated into Windows Explorer for manually updates and commits. Other with experience would need to comment.