# VS2010 Express with Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, codeplex, team-explorer

I'm using VS2010 Express edition and want to connect to codeplex.  I downloaded Team Explorer 2010, but am unable to find the Team Explorer view in VS.  Is it possible to use team explorer with VS2010 express?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907357/can-visual-studio-2010-express-connect-to-team-foundation-server-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions) previous SO answer, it says that Team Explorer support is missing from the Express edition.
Edit: That's for 2008 but I believe it holds true for VS 2010 as well.

Comment: Is the Team Explorer available now for VS Express 2012?

Comment: @ray247 I googled and found this link - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/09/12/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop-is-here.aspx
From reading that, I think it might be available for VS Express 2012 for Windows Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try the keyboard shortcut of Ctrl+\, Ctrl+M. If that does not work then, no you can not use TFS with VS Express.