# What's missing from Visual C++ 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-express, visual-c++-2010, visual-c++-2010-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “missing” in the Visual Studio Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions)

Specifically for 2010, specifically for C++... what's missing Vs Professional/Premium (annoying the standard version is now named Professional)?

Comment: BTW, should I tag with all of these or are tags hierarchical at all?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions

Comment: Not a duplicate, that thread is mostly discussing 2008 and is also general rather than specific to one language.

Comment: I guess people just like closing without reading...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/

Express versions don't have:

- Plugins
- Class Designer
- Code Analysis
- Creating 64-bit programs
- Creating for Itanium processors
- Creating for Windows Mobile
- Creating for Office using Visual Studio Tools for Office.

Express versions have but with limited functionality:

- External Tools
- Refactoring
- Debugging
- Integration with MSDN
- Installator Creator

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Svisstack's answer, express lacks support for MFC. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx) guy found a way to do MFC in VS2008e, but I have no idea if this hack works in VS2010e.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a special express build for Windows Phone 7 development.

http://www.microsoft.com/express/phone/