# Does VC++ 2010 Express not have std::thread?

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Does VC++ 2010 Express not have std::thread? I am using the multi-threaded DLL. The compiler does not find the header file , nor does it recognize std::thread::hardware_concurrency. Is there some setting I need to fix, or is it just missing? (July 2012, latest and greatest.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` was added in C++11 which is still relatively recent.

VC++ 2010 doesn't support it. But VC++ 2012 should have it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know, will it be available in a freebie compiler like VC++ Express, and if so when?

Comment: Express will have the same C++11 support as the Pro version.

Comment: AFAIK, the things they nuke from the Express versions are not language related. Just usability features.

Comment: Here's a list of things that aren't in VC++ Express 2010: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164970/whats-missing-from-visual-c-2010-express I'd assume that VC++ 2012 wouldn't be too different.