# Can Express versions of Visual Studio still use Add-ins I create?

Tags: add-in, visual-studio-express

Pretty simple question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

One of the things not allowed/enabled with the express editions is loading of add-ins.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-express-editions).

And directly from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=727BCFB0-B575-47AB-9FD8-4EE067BB3A37&displaylang=en).