# How to build 64bit applications in MSVC++ 2008 Express?

Tags: visual-c++, x86, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm running 32bit Windows and I'm wondering, is it possible to build 64bit apps in MSVC++ 2008 Express Edition ?
If yes, how ?

Comment: It's cumbersome, but possible. See the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376198/configuring-64-bit-compilation-inside-visual-studio-2008-express-edition-vs2008

Answer (score 0):

Generally, VS2008 is able to build 64bit app. You can do that by:

- Left click on solution and pick "Configuration manager"
- Click on "Active Solution Platform" combo box (there should be selected "Win32") and select "new"
- new dialog appears, so just select targer platform Itanium/x64
- click on OK, done :)

Comment: As the link that Andrey gave explains, the Express edition requires some manual configuration to get it to the point where it will offer you the x64 target platform.