# .pyd import error appears after OS reinstall. Was there a dependency change?

Tags: python, dll, orange

I am coding in Python 2.7, leveraging via [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si/) and its accompanying packages (numpy, scipy, etc.) For work-related reasons, my development environment is Aptana 3 on a Windows 7 x64 platform. I recently had a motherboard failure and have reinstalled everything relevant I can think of.

Unfortunately, a critical Orange extension (orangecontrib.earth) now fails to load. The accompanying DLL, `_earth.pyd`, is the culprit. The error message from the python console is

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

but since `_earth.pyd` is in the correct place, I must conclude that it is actually not loading. Investigating with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for x64 v2.2  claims the following missing dependencies for `_earth.pyd`:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll;
mscvr90.dll;
python27.dll.
```

I *know* this can't be simply a 32- vs. 64-bit problem as the same code loaded on the previous installation.

---

Update 2:

Installations of dependencies:

libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll -- Was already installed as part of MinGW at C:\MinGW\bin
python27.dll -- Was already installed at C:\Python27
msvcr90.dll -- now installed as part of Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express SP1

( Installed versions of Visual C++ include:

2005 SP1 x32, x64
2008 SP1 x32, x64 
2008 express SP1 x32
2010 SP1 x32, x64
2012 SP1 x32, x64)

Comment: Are python 2.7, gcc and the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 runtime (`mscvr90.dll`) installed correctly. Can you find those 3 dlls on your system?

Comment: @theB -- 1) python27.dll is exactly where it should be in C:\Python27.

2) GCC is installed as part of the MinGW package, which I had on the previous implementation as well. It lives in C:\MinGW\bin.

3) As for Microsoft Visual C++, the currently installed versions are 2005 x64, 2010 x86 and 2010 x64.

Comment: @theB -- msvcr90.dll seems to be the missing piece, but I can't seem to find a version of it to install. Putting 2008 SP1 on hasn't worked, either x32 or x64.

Comment: You'll probably need to find the specific version of the redistributable that Orange is looking for. (On my system here I've got 4 versions of the 08 C++ redist. 2 x86 and 2 x64) I've not found specifics, but it may be worth checking the orange documentation to see if they outline their dependencies.

Comment: @theB -- The orangecontrib.earth documentation specified Microsoft Visual C++ Express 2008. This is now installed and I finally have a msvcr90.dll, but there is still no joy in Mudville. 

There appears to be a number of problems with that particular implementation (see [link](https://jenshuebel.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/visual-c-2008-express-edition-and-64-bit-targets/) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376198/configuring-64-bit-compilation-inside-visual-studio-2008-express-edition-vs2008).)