# Visual Web Developer 2010 Express - limitations on accessing remote databases?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, oracle10g, vwdexpress

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express on my laptop to run some ASP.Net which is trying to access an Oracle database on another machine.

I've having some difficulties executing ...

```
SqlConnection myConnectionTest = new SqlConnection(s);
```

... and before I went any further I thought I should check .... does VWD2010 impose some sort of limitations on accessing remote databases ?

[Not sure if this is relevant the connectionStrings entry to oracle is using a TNS-less connection string like this :

```
<add name="ABC" connectionString="providerName="OraOLEDB.Oracle";Data Source=//foo.bar.com:1521/dev10.foo.bar.com;User Id=auserid;Password=apwd;"/>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to connectionstrings.com, a TSN-less connection string has the form:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myHost)(PORT=myPort)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MyOracleSID)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

Is '`providerName`' also accepted?

Comment: Would you mind looking at the 'answer' I've entered below (or will have) as you've raised an interesting point which first made me wonder about whether there was some limitation

Comment: OK I'm marking this as the correct answer because it provided useful information and allowed me to move towards a resolution of this problemw which was not related to Visual Web Developer Express and was instead related to my not having installed the ODD.NET drivers (even thought I thought I had !).

Answer (score 0):

**There are no limitations that would prevent access to an Oracle Database**

[What is "missing" in the Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions)

**This may be of some value:**

[Tips on Oracle Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Mitch Wheat

Interesting point about the provider aspect of the connection string. If I don't put it into the string so that the connection string looks like this ...

```
<add name="ABC" providerName="OraOLEDB.Oracle" connectionString="Data Source=//foo.bar.com:1521/dev10.foo.bar.com;User Id=auserid;Password=apwd;"/>
```

... then I get an error which suggests that VWDC is trying to connect to a SQL Server database !

```
Ex.Message = A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
```

... the way that it seems to be defaulting to SQL Server which was what made me wonder initially whether there was some lim itation within VWDC.

Any comments on this welcome !