# Visual Studio 2010 Express Limitations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

What are the limitations of VS2010 C# Express Edition compared with the paid for versions? I was mostly looking into what sort of applications I can build, in VS Express I only have the option of Console, Winform and DLL, etc. I read that you can build services and add - ins for office programs, is this functionality available in Professional/Ultimate etc versions? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<del>There's a comparison chart [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison#expressCompareTable)</del> - You'll need VS Professional to develop Office Plugins.

Although previous version, there is a definitive overview of the VS2008 Express limitations in in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express) also explains the differences.

**Edit**

The comparison chart link is dead. For 2012:

- Visual Studio 2012 (Web Only) comparison [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms349441(v=vs.100).aspx), and in [this Programmer's post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166716/visual-studio-2012-express-vs-professional)
- [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408610/limitations-of-visual-studio-2012-express-desktop) addresses the Desktop comparison.

Comment: IMHO, the most common annoyances are 1) having to switch between C# and Web editions when building a largish app 2) Lack of add-ins e.g. for version control, but otherwise the VS Expresses are great.

Comment: Yeah I definitely agree with you!

Comment: Unfortunately, as of Mar 2013, this link doesn't compare Express to the other versions.

Comment: @chessofnerd Thanks, you are right. Unfortunately I couldn't find an old cached version on [webarchive.org] either. I've updated as best as I could for 2012.

Answer (score 6):

The Express edition does not come with, nor does it grant you permission to distribute, the Microsoft C++ runtime redistributable packages. So the users of the software you build with the Express edition will have to download & run the installers themselves.