# No WPF/Silverlight in VS2012?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I have installed VS2012 on a windows 8 machine and surprisingly doesn't show any WPF or Silverlight option when I create a project.

Am I missing something here?! In fact, it is not the way it used to be in VS2010. I only can see it as template under Visual C# which again it is under Online.

Why is that?

Comment: What sort of project did you create? Or are you looking for the WPF/Silverlight project templates under the Visual C# option?

Comment: Just checked - both sections are present (Windows and Silverlight if to expand the C# section). You must have installed VS Express instead of the full version.

Comment: yes I did ... should I uninstall it and install the full version? I thought this free version have it. any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install "Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop"....it's a different edition which has restored the WPF capability.

- http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-windows-desktop
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/09/12/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop-is-here.aspx

To help decide if it's got all the capabilities you need:

- [Limitations of Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408610/limitations-of-visual-studio-2012-express-desktop)