# How do I extract an interface with Visual Studio 2013 (Express)

Tags: c#, interface, visual-studio-2013, refactoring

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web.

I am trying to extract the interface from my class, but when I right click on the class and select the "Refactor" menu, I don't have an "Extract Interface" option.

[image: Showing the Refactor Menu without the Extract Interface option]

Have I set up something wrong?  How do I get the Extract Interface option.  I've gone through all the menu options that I can find, but can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. I have seen this in full version and it is hard to miss, but I checked the Express edition and it isn't there. I wasn't able to find any official Microsoft documentation stating this for the 2013 edition, but previous versions of Visual Studio Express have only included [limited refactoring support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms349441(v=vs.110).aspx).  The differences in the 2012 editions are cataloged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408610/limitations-of-visual-studio-2012-express-desktop).

Answer (score 1):

Use `CTRL+R, I` shortcut. It will open extract interface window.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx