# Windows Service in C# Express

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a service with Visual Express for C#. But cannot find the template. I want to create a simple service which reads every X hours or day an XML files containing date and time and attributes.

Then the services will send a syslog message to a remote host containing the task attribute in message.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Windows Scheduler, and call a normal C# program to handle the XML file.

Comment: +1: for something that works "once every X hours", you don't need a service

Comment: +1: likewise. No immediate need to have a service hogging around.

Answer (score 1):

<s>AFAIK you cannot create windows services with Visual Studio Express.</s>

EDIT: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx) a service is created in VS 2005 Express, so it is still possible.

EDIT1: [How to: Write Services Programmatically in VS 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Windows Service is just a piece of code, either you have template for it or you write it by yourself.

Comment: Right. Also see this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions/352373#352373)