# Is Visual Studio express less resource intensive than Visual Studio Pro?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-express

I have VS 2010 at work, but at home I was thinking of just installing the express version since it might be less resource intensive?

Comment: Well, sure, the Express edition supports only one language and no add-ins.  Which makes it impossible for it to consume *more* resources.

Comment: One language? Which one would that be?  I thought it supported C#, VB.NET, C++, etc.

Comment: This is all a heckofalot easier if you actually *try* it.  Pick one of the editions from this page: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is *much* less resource intensive.

It also has many less features.

I suggest reading [What is “missing” in the Visual Studio 2008 Express Editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86614/1583) before making a decision.

Comment: I don't use the cheap home laptop for much development, so not looking for much features, but being less resource intensive would be nice.  Does the same apply to SQL Server Express vs SQL Server Developer?

Comment: I read the comparisons and nothing major jumps out, but does VS Express support Resharper and if I want to eventually upgrade to Pro, is it like Windows Anytime Upgrade where I just specify the proper key or is it a completely new download/install?

Comment: @Xaisoft - Resharper is an _add on_. Add ons are not supported on Express editions.

Comment: @Xaisoft - Pro and Express are separate downloads. You _can_ have them installed side by side.

Comment: OK, the Reshaper add-on might be a deal breaker, but if I can have them side by side that would be nice.  Thanks Oded.