# How To Add Project In Visual C# 2008 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am developing an application where i will have to add  a separate project 
to the one being developed in order to add it as a reference.
The issue is that in visual c#2008 express,i can not find the:

```
                “Add...”, “Existing Project”
```

Option when i right click on the File menu in the IDE.
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's highly likely that this is an inherent limitation in the Express editions of Visual Studio.

Compile the original project, and add a reference to the resulting DLL instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an enforced limit of Visual Studio Express.  You can see more about the limitations in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions).