# Machine Name for remote debugging does not exist in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Hi I am using Visual Studio 2012 Desktop, I am trying to do remote debugging following the steps below for my WPF C# project. But my menu is not the same as shown in that link, I don't have the Machine Name textbox. How come ?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a menu, "Debug" is a tab on the project's property page.

- In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, and then click Properties.
- On the mywin4m properties page, click Debug.

[image]

If you mean you have Visual Studio 2012 *Express* for Desktop, you're out of luck: that edition [doesn't have remote debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86562/what-is-missing-in-the-visual-studio-2008-express-editions). Try Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Comment: Yes, indeed that is the reason. I am using Express edition. Downloaded community edition now.